# npm boostrap, js doesnt work on react project

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, npm

I'm making a react project, where I need to put a navbar, I installed bootstrap with

```
npm install bootstrap
```

and I imported it in my index.js like this :

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

I put the bootstrap's documentation navbar exemple in my component, but the button doesn't show the links.
Here's my code :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hidden brand</a>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

I tried to add  :

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';
```

in my index.js file but, it didn't work

Do you have any idea, to solve this ?

Comment: What kind of setup are you using? Create React App?

Comment: @yuriy636 yes create react app

Comment: does you button show the different links when you clic on it ?

Comment: I've just tried to reproduce the bug and I had it, I just dit an npx create-react-app , install boostrap, paste my code for the navbar but it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

First install bootstrap `npm install bootstrap` and than install jquery and popper.js to, `npm install jquery popper.js`.

Add all to **index.js**

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Popper from 'popper.js';
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me :/

Comment: Try follow steps form this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-bootstrap-in-react-js/)

Comment: did you try it ? I followed the steps but it won't work

Comment: When I was doing react web project I was using Material UI https://mui.com/ check it out, I have found it easy to use and those components are styled already.